# Java Splitting A Sentence

Tags: java, twitter, split

I am writing a program for Twitter. It will read a tweet and get the hashtags in it.

The problem is, I couldn't split it. For example, `"I love #computers so much."` in this one, I need to obtain only the `"computers"` part.

I thought about using split function by using `#` but it will split the sentence in a half so still, it won't be a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the code you have written so far

Comment: You first split it with # and then again you have to split  it with space

Comment: how about just using basic indexOf and subString

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to split on the # indeed. After that you want to have the word. So split on the " " space :).

```
string="I love #computers so much.";
String[] parts = string.split("#");
String part1 = parts[0]; // I love 
String part2 = parts[1]; // computers so much.

String[] parts2 = part2.split(" ");
String output = parts2[0];
```

The above should work, haven't tested it though.

If there are multiple hashtages the above won't work, try the below one:

```
String string="I love #computers so #much omg #lol .";
    String[] stringParts = string.split("#");

    //'delete' first element.
    String[] parts = Arrays.copyOfRange(stringParts, 1, stringParts.length);

    int i = 0;
    String[] output = new String[10];

    for(String part : parts)
    {
        if(part.contains(" "))
        {
            String[] parts2 = part.split(" ");
            output[i] = parts2[0];
            i++;
        }
    }
```

The only problem is with this code, that you need a space otherwise you will have different characters in your word.

Comment: What about tweet like "I love #computers so #much.", including more than one '#' character?

Answer (score 0):

You would do well to take a look at solving the problem using regular expressions.... try something like (?<=#)\w+   -- it will return all alpha numerics after the #, while not capturing the #.  You may want to change the \w to include additional characters as required.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to obtain the hash tags from the tweet. Something like:

```
    String sentence = "I love #computers and #something_Else so much";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#\\S+");

    List<String> hashTags = new ArrayList<>();

    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(sentence);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        hashTags.add(matcher.group(0));
    }

    System.out.println(hashTags);
```